# Login Requirement for some page in my web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization

i have question about authentication and login.

i have e-servcie to be used from pubice user's for job request , this e-service have 3 steps in 3 page and no need to login, so any one can access to this service from our website.

and as u know for each e-service their is application to manage the requset, this application have login and it's work ok.

i put this smiple code in web config:

```
    <authorization>
        <deny users = "?" />

     <allow users ="*" />

    </authorization>
```

with this code all the page redirect to login page even those related to e-service.

how could i keep e-service pages away from login check.

by the way i have 2 Master page: 1 for e-service and 1 for managment.

i use Asp.Net 4.0 with C#

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To keep a page out of login check, you should add:

```
<location path="yourpage.htm">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Thanks Cuong Le for ur replay: 
but this not work with me,
 when i add <Location> tage with my page which i want to keep it out , i got 2 type of error:
 1- in the menation page i got message about "section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level " RELATED TO <membership>
-------------
2- when i open Pages which included in authorization method for managment got this erroe "using System.Linq;" , which it not found if i delete  <location>.